# how to access "extracted links" from rule class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

this is a small code that is collecting links from start_urls and print on the console, I want to know how we can access/see extracted links list (queue), I have searched a lot but didn't find any attribute that can return me a list of extracted urls. if anyone know please let me know. thanks

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'
    start_urls = ['https://www.pluralsight.com/', 'http://books.toscrape.com/','https://stackoverflow.com/']

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
    }

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse', follow=True)]

    def parse(self, response):
        absolute_url = response.request.url
        print(absolute_url)
```

Comment: if you want to extract all the urls from the webpage, i have a scripts that does that, [github link](https://github.com/jedimasterbot/python-scripts/tree/main/Links%20From%20Webpage)

Comment: I can also extract all links from the webpage but i want to see/access those links which are extracted by rule class.